# model self-dependency (one-to-many field) implementation

Tags: django, one-to-many

I would like to implement a model with self-dependency. Say instance People_A may depend on People_B and People_C.
I first implement this model with many to many key.

```
class People(models.Model):

dependency = models. ManyToManyField ('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

But the result is that if People_A depend on People_B will result in People_B depend also on People_A. That’s something I don’t want to have.

Then I implement it with foreign key.

```
class People(models.Model):

dependency = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

But this doesn’t work also. If People_A depend on People_B, then no other People could depend on People_B. It will cover the old dependency with the latest dependency.

Any clue would be thankful

Comment: Just to clarify ForeighKey: `If People_A depend on People_B, then no other People could depend on People_B`. Other people still can depend on People_B, but People_A now can't have other dependency, than to People_B

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
dependencies = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) for symmetrical.

Comment: You are awesome!