# Problems with the Follow function

Tags: python, django, database

I want created a kind social network for my school in django.
My Problem is that I create a follow function and django give me a Error Response.
How can I handle that?

django code:

```
class User(User):
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


class Following_User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_follow = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and heres the Error Response:

```
ERRORS:

cherry.Following_User.user_follow: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Following_User.user_follow' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Following_User.user_id'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Following_User.user_follow' or 'Following_User.user_id'.
cherry.Following_User.user_id: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Following_User.user_id' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Following_User.user_follow'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Following_User.user_id' or 'Following_User.user_follow'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [model self-dependency (one-to-many field) implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613013/model-self-dependency-one-to-many-field-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a model that contains two fields that as foreign key of another model, you need to specify the `related_name` for each of them.

```
class Following_User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following_user_id")
    user_follow = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following_user_follow")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

The reason to have `related_name` is so that django would give you reverse relation if you want to query from the foreign key. For single field that has the relationship with current model, django gives you a default one `blahfield_set`, but in this case the `related_name` would be used to remove ambiguity.